# Consistency in the appearances of loops from rectangular nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I would like to have a left-positioned loop "look the same" as a below-positioned loop emanating from a rectangular node.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzstyle{rect} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum       height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]

 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \node (A) (r) [rect] {Rectangle};
 \path[->] (r) edge  [loop below] node {Below} ();
 \path[->] (r) edge  [loop left] node {Left} ();
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

For example the left loop is fatter and bigger. I want it to start and finish in the middle of the left-vertical side of the rectangle and be of the same size/shape as the lower loop.

Thanks

Ron

**Ans:**

As per Harish Kumar's answer (with some minor configurations)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (r) [rect] {Rectangle};
\path[->] (r) edge  [loop below] node {Below} ();
\path[->] (r.185) edge  [out=195, in=170,distance=0.8cm] node[anchor=east] {Left}(r.175);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both the loops set their origin from the center of the node while calculating parameters and since the width and height of the node is different, they come out in different sizes. You may draw the loops by yourselves in such cases.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzstyle{rect} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum       height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]

 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[draw,minimum size=1cm] (a){};
 \path[->] (a) edge  [loop below] node {Below} ();
 \path[->] (a) edge  [loop left] node {Left} ();
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \node (A) (r) [rect] {Rectangle};
 \path[->] (r.300) edge  [out=300,in=240,distance=1.5cm]node[anchor=north] {Below} (r.240) ;
 \path[->] (r.190) edge  [out=190,in=170,distance=1.5cm] node[anchor=east] {Left} (r.170);
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

You may have to adjust the `looseness`/`tension` to make them exactly similar.